How does Husserl explain the common perception of an object?
Husserl considers that the intentional term, the noema, is within the immanence of intentional consciousness. (Here, I will not distinguish between noema and object, as some Fregean readings do.) In this sense, the noema is entirely transcendent to the act, the noesis, or the lived experience of it, which "intends" the transcendent noema by relying on sensible experiences or hyletic data.
This means that the noema, as transcendent as it may be to the lived experience, and despite possessing an irreducible otherness to the act that intends it, is always and in every case correlative to the act. To affirm the contrary would be to fall into the naïve attitude that transcends what is given within the intentional whole.
Now then, how should we understand the "common perception" of an object? When two subjects look at the "same" place, how is this explained phenomenologically? There is no need to naïvely appeal to a common object represented by our noemas, and it would also be an unjustified assumption to think that a wall "divides" our first-person lived acts—such a belief would smuggle in the "natural attitude" here. However, if noemas are not identical and there is no basis for asserting that they are essentially different (if I am understanding Husserl correctly), what is it that "synchronises" our gazes in a kind of pre-established harmony at a shared perceptual locus?

Indeed your unsettled confusion about noema is very akin to the problem of other minds which itself could be said to be a kind of unclear and nondistinctive formed noematic image incomparable across different minds in principle and they all dwell in some storehouse per yogacara school. And one possible way out is the doctrine of pure formative and comparable acts of intention precedes both the realms of noesis and noema ontically as hinted by ancient yogacara abhidharmas…

Husserl's student Heidegger tried solve this problem using his famous being of the there since absolutely speaking in your above mode there's indeed hardly any exact justification for any two different subjects to share the same perception of an object by looking at the same place in their own idiosyncratic way, only after thrown to the opened-up world and being there looking at same place calmly, they can possible understand the common part. This could be said to be similar to Mahayana's doctrine in the ontic prior sense that being here as subject source intends to belong to there...

@DoubleKnot Yes, I agree: for Heidegger, the question of whether two "subjects" see "the same thing" is a theoretical one, presupposing a prior moment where that line has not yet been drawn, so the problem is not a "given" at all. But my question is how Husserl resolves the problem.

@DoubleKnot The problem of the "common locus" is, pardon the pun, a "commonplace" in Yogachara, particularly for Dignaga and Dharmakirti. Fundamentally, for them, there is no "common identity" in two perceptions, as the referent is empty. They explain this by appealing to a series of karmic imprints wichin the mind streams that cause two perceptions to present apparently "the same thing," but I have honestly never fully understood the solution they propose, despite agreeing that an object does not have a "common" identity in "two" perceptions.

Husserl's transcendental reduction assumes that intersubjectivity where our shared understanding of a world is grounded in the lifeworld, a pre-given horizon of meaning co-constituted by subjects' Kantian synthesis, essentially an argument by analogy for the problem of other mind. Yet this presupposes that the structures of noesis as acts of consciousness and noema as intended content are comparable across subjects, which is not unlike Platonic forms as you criticized. For Yogis this posited sameness is conventional from alayered storehouse seeds like DNAs but not ultimate per Nāgārjuna...

@DoubleKnot Karmic past is used (among other things) in both Yogachara and Madhyamaka to avoid the allusion to a ‘ready made’ natural world independent of our interests and concerns (although Madhyamaka Prasangika admits the existence of an external world, this too is contained in the conventional dimension as only a nominal imputation). This is why we have to accept a common set of rules, such as abiding by logic in this conversation; not because there is an inherently logical world, but because an infinite series of past actions has been shaping a common set of rules in this way.

@DoubleKnot You are right that it is a presupposition that the noema is comparable between subjects; the problem is that this critique is one made from the ‘natural attitude’ and not made after the phenomenological reduction. In any case, I still don't quite understand how Husserl resolves this issue of intersubjectivity and common perception.

In the natural attitude, one assumes the world exists independently for all observers. However, transcendental reduction brackets this assumption to analyze how the shared world is constituted in consciousness. Husserl argues that intersubjectivity is constituted through the transcendental ego's pairing capacity to empathize others as coherence of expectations. By recognizing other agents as "alter egos," one extends the horizon of possibilities to include shared perceptions which arise from synthesis of individual intentional acts with their universal temporality which are comparable...

@DoubleKnot That's why I say that the Mitwelt that arises from pairing is very similar to a pre-established harmony: pre-reflectively, the "other" is given to me as a counterpart, and this makes my question about whether I live in solipsism or not merely an explanatory assumption that presupposes this prior experience of the other as a similar body with intentionality akin to mine. However, I do not have full access to the other; my personal consciousness does not entirely "touch" the other—it only intuits it empathically. Thus, there is a kind of "synchronization" of intersubjective actions.

Indeed and I never claimed Husserl is beyond Plato, Vasubandhu, Indra's net dependent arisen, Leibnitz, or Kant philosophically...
